# Quels sont les antonymes de l'adjectif « dénutri » et du nom « dénutrition » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, antonyme, fréquence-utilisation

Dans une lecture reliée à une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52278/26366) je suis tombé sur des termes qui m'étaient inconnus : l'adjectif [*dénutri*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9nutri) « qui est atteint de dénutrition » (TLFi), la [*dénutrition*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D1420) étant l'« état pathologique résultant d’une importante carence alimentaire ou de troubles nutritionnels graves » (Ac.9, nouveau, du 19<sup>e</sup>).

- Quels sont les antonymes de l'adjectif *dénutri* et du nom
  *dénutrition* ?
- Ces termes (*dénutri, dénutrition*) sont-ils de notorité publique ?

Answer (score 1):

[Suralimentation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suralimentation) / [Suralimenté](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suralimenter)

> A. − Alimentation supérieure au régime alimentaire normal.

On trouve "dénutrition" et "dénutri" dans tous les dictionnaires, oui.